# Google Drive Uploading multipart mime base64 encoded file w/powershell: malformed multipart body error

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api

Token retrieval all figured out.

Uploading files to Google Drive.

Getting error

Here is the powershell command I'm using:

`$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart" -Method Post -Headers $uploadHeaders -Body $uploadBody`

Here is the string for the variable $uploadBody

```
--314159265358979323846
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

    {
    "description":  "TestCSV",
    "name":  "test-emp.csv",
    "originalFilename":  "test-emp.csv"
}

--314159265358979323846
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


    c0FNQWNjb3VudE5hbWUsRU1QX05VTQ0KYnNtaXRoLDc3Mzk5Mg0KbHNvbmcsMzM3MTEwDQpnc3Vkbyw2NDkwNTc
--314159265358979323846--
```

This fails -  only changed the data file:

```
--314159265358979323846
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

    {
    "description":  "TestCSV",
    "name":  "csv3.csv",
    "originalFilename":  "csv3.csv"
}

--314159265358979323846
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


    c2VxLGZpcnN0LGxhc3QNCjEsQW15LEJhcmtlcg0KMixMZWUsU2FsYXphcg0KMyxFc3RlbGxhLEtlbm5lZHkNCg
--314159265358979323846--
```

For completeness, here is the header IDictionary param for $uploadHeaders

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                                           
Authorization                  Bearer ya29.GlxbBiz86xKlRnjzQY2z70vHtWfL4sr28BvX-OKio8PbcEfJ0l7tQgx9btNqMdanYXG_WzSD74WD_15903vn0mYO0G0uI8lez5g77Z_W0gKrIRh_s...
Content-Type                   multipart/related; boundary=314159265358979323846                                                                               
Content-Length                 400
```

I've read a great deal on this and have made sure there were two `r`n before payload.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you uploading a file?  Just use the `-InFile` parameter.  There is very little need to part your file manually anymore.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much #TheIncorribible1 !

I have changed it as follows:
<pre>

Comment: That made the file ok.  But the title is "Untitled" & I can't seem to change it.

Ideas?

Comment: Apologies, I did not post this sooner:

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename the file after uploading it.

```
$sourceFile = 'C:\temp\allisv22018201810101009.csv'

$sourceItem = Get-Item $sourceFile

# If uploading to a Team Drive, set this to 'true'
$supportsTeamDrives = 'false'

# Set the file metadata
$uploadMetadata = @{
    originalFilename=$sourceItem.Name
    name=$sourceItem.Name
    description="TestCSV"
}

# Set the upload headers
$uploadHeaders = @{
    Authorization="Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Perform the upload
try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart" -Method Post -Headers $uploadHeaders -InFile $SourceFile
    $urifile = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$($response.id)"
    $renameResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urifile -Method Patch -Headers $uploadHeaders -Body '{ "name":"HappyFile.csv" }'
```

If you successfully upload your file, it will return the value in **$urifile** and you can use that to rename the file.